# Location of a permission

Tags: android, google-license-manager

I am making an AAR for licensing functionality. I plan to use it in multiple applications.

As per documentation, licensing implementation needs a permission in manifest file: "com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"

I am not sure where should this permission be kept,in application's manifest file or library project's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

All your library related permissions/metadata/activities relevant info should be declared in your library manifest file

Comment: Thanks NIPHIN for the inputs.